# Adding data to database Android

Tags: android, sql, database

I am starting off with Android and have this class with a list of ingredients. There are checkboxes for each ingredient and an add button. I wish to transfer this data to a local database but not sure how to go about it. Do I need a Database helper class? Please give me some example of code or how to implement this in my onclick method. The following is my code...

**Tab2Activity.java**

```
public class Tab2Activity extends Fragment {

public ArrayList<String> shoppingList;
public ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxes;
```

//  public CheckBox cb;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_two, container, false);

    shoppingList = new ArrayList<String>();
    checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_two, container, false);
   // RelativeLayout s = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_two, container, false);
   // RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)s.findViewById(R.layout.text);

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    String ingredientsString = b.getString("ingredients");

    System.out.println("string: " + ingredientsString);
    String[] ingredients = ingredientsString.split(",");

    System.out.println("size: " + ingredients.length);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(getActivity());
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    for(int i = 0; i <ingredients.length; i++) {
        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        cb.setText(ingredients[i]);
        cb.setTag("checkbox" + i);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.getTag();
                    shoppingList.add(cb.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("ADDING: " + cb.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    shoppingList.remove(cb.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("REMOVING: " + cb.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });
        ll.addView(cb);
    }
    Button button = new Button(getActivity());
    button.setText("Add to list");
    button.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String list = "";

            for (int x=0; x<shoppingList.size(); x++)
                list += shoppingList.get(x) + "\n";

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Save List")
                    .setMessage("Add following items to list?\n\n" + list)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
    });
    ll.addView(button);
    l.addView(sv);
    return l;

   // return v;
}
```

}

UPDATE: I have made a database class...Do you think I am on the right track?

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Ingredients_DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "INGREDIENTS";
public static final String Col_1 = "TITLE";

public DBhelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(TITLE STRING PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TITLE TEXT");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Col_1, Title);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have put my database class above. Do you think I am on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

There are several [options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Storing it in the local database may or may not be the best way. Either way, the official documentation can guide you through how to use any of the following options:

- Shared Preferences - Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
- Internal Storage - Store private data on the device memory.
- External Storage - Store public data on the shared external storage.
- SQLite Databases - Store structured data in a private database.
- Network Connection - Store data on the web with your own network server.

See the [Android documentation "Storage Options"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for how to implement whichever one works best for your situation.